Black Screen on Iphone. but, working on Emulator
i have create flutter project. an i already do on iphone 15 (17.4) emulator on mac. but, after i do archives and build the ios installer (.ipa) and install on my iphone 13 (17.6) is black screen after splash screen. and this is my code for appdelegate
import UIKit
import Flutter
import Firebase
import UserNotifications

@main
@objc class AppDelegate: FlutterAppDelegate, MessagingDelegate {

  override func application(
    _ application: UIApplication,
    didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplication.LaunchOptionsKey: Any]?
  ) -> Bool {
    FirebaseApp.configure()
      
      let flutterEngine = FlutterEngine(name: "my flutter engine")
          flutterEngine.run()
      
      GeneratedPluginRegistrant.register(with: flutterEngine)
    // Set up push notifications
    UNUserNotificationCenter.current().delegate = self

    Messaging.messaging().delegate = self

    let authOptions: UNAuthorizationOptions = [.alert, .badge, .sound]
        UNUserNotificationCenter.current().requestAuthorization(
          options: authOptions
        ) { granted, error in
          if let error = error {
            print("Error requesting notification authorization: \(error)")
          } else {
            print("Notification authorization granted: \(granted)")
          }
        }

      application.registerForRemoteNotifications()
      
      // Set up the root view controller
          window = UIWindow(frame: UIScreen.main.bounds)
          let flutterViewController = FlutterViewController(engine: flutterEngine, nibName: nil, bundle: nil)
          window?.rootViewController = flutterViewController
          window?.makeKeyAndVisible()
      
    return super.application(application, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions: launchOptions)
  }

  // Handle incoming notifications
    override func userNotificationCenter(_ center: UNUserNotificationCenter, didReceive response: UNNotificationResponse, withCompletionHandler completionHandler: @escaping () -> Void) {
    let userInfo = response.notification.request.content.userInfo
    Messaging.messaging().appDidReceiveMessage(userInfo)
    completionHandler()
  }

    override func userNotificationCenter(_ center: UNUserNotificationCenter, willPresent notification: UNNotification, withCompletionHandler completionHandler: @escaping (UNNotificationPresentationOptions) -> Void) {
    let userInfo = notification.request.content.userInfo
    Messaging.messaging().appDidReceiveMessage(userInfo)
    completionHandler([.alert, .badge, .sound])
  }

  // Handle registration for remote notifications
  override func application(_ application: UIApplication, didRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithDeviceToken deviceToken: Data) {
    Messaging.messaging().apnsToken = deviceToken
  }

  // Handle receiving registration token
  func messaging(_ messaging: Messaging, didReceiveRegistrationToken fcmToken: String?) {
    print("FCM registration token: \(String(describing: fcmToken))")
    // You can send the token to your server or handle it as needed
  }
}

i'm stuck in this process. and i don't know what is the error on my device
